# Automatically click href link on document ready

Tags: jquery, click

I have a page with a list of links. Among the links is this one:

```js
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('content_0$rptLeftNavExternal$ctl00$rptLeftNavInternal$ctl11$CheckBox_PublicationType','')" id="content_0_rptLeftNavExternal_rptLeftNavInternal_0_CheckBox_PublicationType_11">Data Sheets</a>
```

Clicking the link produces a dynamic list of items in the content area - without reloading the page.

With jQuery, what I'd like is (1) for the page to fully load, then (2) have the link automatically clicked.

I've read the pages of those with a similar issue and came up with this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#content_0_rptLeftNavExternal_rptLeftNavInternal_0_CheckBox_PublicationType_11").click(function() {
    function() { __doPostBack('content_0$rptLeftNavExternal$ctl00$rptLeftNavInternal$ctl11$CheckBox_PublicationType',''); }
});

});
```

However, it doesn't work. Nothing happens.

If anyone can explain/show me what's wrong with the code above, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks.

Stephen

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually adds a clickhandler to your `a` element.

For the function to execute you need, however, not to attacj a handler or click the link, but just execute its handler the following way for example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  __doPostBack('content_0$rptLeftNavExternal$ctl00$rptLeftNavInternal$ctl11$CheckBox_PublicationType',''); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.click(function() {` attaches a click *handler* to your link.
You want to just execute the function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  __doPostBack('content_0$rptLeftNavExternal$ctl00$rptLeftNavInternal$ctl11$CheckBox_PublicationType',''); }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#blah")` is used to refer to the DOM element with `id="blah"`. The anchor tag you posted does not have an `id` attribute, this your jQuery expression refers to no elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you write :

```
$("#object").click(function(){ ...});
```

You're adding a `click event handler` on the object.
If you want to launch the event you have to use

```
$("#object").click();
```

But in your case why don't you use directly the call ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  __doPostBack('content_0$rptLeftNavExternal$ctl00$rptLeftNavInternal$ctl11$CheckBox_PublicationType','');    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function has an overload to [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) another handler to your element. This is the one you are calling. If you do not give it a parameter, the parameterless overload is called, which will click on your link.